# Android - Handle global configuration changes

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

I'm writing a service that tracks system changes, meaning, I'm willing to track whenever a keyboard becomes visible / hidden **for any application**.

To achieve the following task, i built a small Activity that launches a services

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

The manifest.xml itself

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="somepackage">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the service itself:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public MyService() {
    }

    private static final String TAG =
            "abbeyservice";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    }
}
```

Problem is I'm notified for changes within, and only for my activity. Which is seen as a white screen for unknown reasons(even though i didn't use SetContentView(..))

Comment: *for unknown reasons(even though i didn't use SetContentView(..)* that *is* the reason

Comment: `android:configChanges` is not a valid manifest property for `<service>`. This is ignored. Your IDE should have told you that.

Comment: 1. I do get notified when my white Activity is rotated
2. How do i get notified about keyboard changes?

Answer (score 1):

When you talk of "keyboard" you are talking about the soft keyboard. This doesn't result in a configuration change, as the configuration has not changed.

There are devices with hardware keyboards that slide out, so they generate a configuration change event when they are slid out or back in again. There is also a possibility to attach an external keyboard to some Android devices and the act of connecting or disconnecting a hardware keyboard also generates a configuration change event.

To detect if the keyboard is shown in your own app, see 
[How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)

As far as I know, there is no way to find out if the soft keyboard is shown in another app.